# Position of Forge Viewer Toolbar

Tags: css, autodesk-forge

Is there any way to override the style 'left' of the Toolbar in a Forge Viewer? For some reason it is set to calc(50% - xx px). It should just be calc(50%), which puts it in the middle.

I can't seem to find the documentation of the config object that can be passed to GuiViewer3D, but I'm guessing this could be the key.

[image: app screen dump as it is]

[image: app screen dump as it should be]

Comment: Hi, What version of the viewer are you currently using? also needs to be the same for the CSS library of the viewer. If you are not sure you can check by simply typing LMV_VIEWER_VERSION on the dev tools console

Comment: Hi Jaime. That was it. Thank you so much. I was running a v1 viewer (.../v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.13) with v2 CCS.

Comment: Hi Mads, great to hear, would you mind marking the previous comment as a solution so we can move on from this case and people with similar issues in the future know what to check for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jaime. I can't mark it as a solution if it's not an answer. What you have posted is just a comment. If you copy the content to an answer I will sure mark it as the solution. Best Mads

Comment: As a general rule, you can simply overwrite the viewer css with custom css in case you want to modify the UI look. There is not much APIs exposed which allows to customize directly the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS library of the viewer needs to be the same version as the JS libraries. If you are not sure what the current library is you can check by simply typing LMV_VIEWER_VERSION on the dev tools console.